# Консольный ввод с аргументом

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, arraylist

Задачка.
Разработайте список дел, управляемый командами в консоли. Команды: LIST, ADD, EDIT, DELETE.

LIST - отображает ящики с их серийными номерами;
ADD - добавляет дело в конец списка или дело в определенное место, перемещая остальные дела вперед, если указать число;
EDIT - заменяет регистр указанным числом;
DELETE - удаляет.

Примеры команд

LIST
ADD Что-то
ADD 4 Что-то на четвертом месте
EDIT 3 Новое название дела
DELETE 7

Вопрос :

Как вывести в консоли команду с аргументом типа «ADD 4»?
Мой код:

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.io.IOException;


   public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  ArrayList<String> todoList = new ArrayList<>() {{
   add(0, "Get up in the morning");
   add(1, "Wash up");
   add(2, "Put yourself in order");
   add(3, "Put the planet in order");
   add(4, "Weed out the baobabs");
    }};

   String nameOfDeal;
   int dealNumber ;
  String editName;
  int deleteDeal;

  String text = "WELCOME TO THE DAY TO-DO LIST. SELECT THE ACTION: \n\nLIST - display the to-do list 
  on the screen" +
"\nADD - add to the to-do list" +
"\nEDIT - replace the case with the specified number;" +
"\nDELETE - delete a case from the list" +
"\nEXIT - exit";
System.out.println(text);
```

System.out.println("\nENTER: ");

```
  while (true) {
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 switch (sc.nextLine())
  {
   case "LIST":
  System.out.println("TO-DO LIST: ");
  for (String s : todoList) {
    System.out.println(todoList.indexOf(s) +" "+ s);
  }

  continue;

case "ADD":
  System.out.println("Enter which case you want to add ");
  Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
  nameOfDeal = scanner1.next();
  todoList.add(nameOfDeal);
  System.out.println("The case has been added and is listed under No.: " + todoList.size());
  System.out.println();
  for (String s : todoList) {
    System.out.println(todoList.indexOf(s) +" "+ s);
  }

  continue;

case "DELETE":
  System.out.println("Enter the index of the case you want to delete");
  Scanner scanner4 = new Scanner(System.in);
  deleteDeal = scanner4.nextInt();
  todoList.remove(deleteDeal);
  for (String s : todoList) {
    System.out.println(todoList.indexOf(s) +" "+ s);
  }
  continue;

case "EDIT":

  System.out.println("Enter index of the case you want to change");
  Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
  dealNumber = scanner2.nextInt();
  todoList.remove(dealNumber);
  System.out.println("Enter a new task instead of the old one");
  Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
  editName = scanner3.nextLine();
  todoList.add(dealNumber, editName);
  for (String s : todoList) {
    System.out.println(todoList.indexOf(s) +" "+ s);
  }
  continue;

default:
  System.out.println("Try again");
  break;

case "EXIT":
  System.out.println("UP TO NEW MEETINGS!");
  break;
 }
 sc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nameOfDeal = scanner1.next();
Использование next() будет возвращать только то, что находится перед пробелом. nextLine() читает всю строку включая пробелы.

Comment: Невнимательность. Спасибо!